# The Taxonomy Module doesn't work in Orchard cms 1.4 version

Tags: orchardcms

I failed to run Taxonomies Module under Orchard 1.4:

Steps:

1. Got and run [the solution](http://orchard.codeplex.com/releases/74491/download/348783) of Orchard
2. Copied in \Orchard.Web\Modules\ the source code of Taxonomy Module got from the CodePlex Taxonomy Module page.
3. Enabled the Module in "Modules" (no errors are shown, no errors in Orchard.Web\App_Data\Logs).
4. Results:

   - No "Taxonomies" menu item in Admin
   - No "Term" (TermPart) and "Taxonomy" (TaxonomyPart) in the list in "Content Parts" of "Content" menu item

Could I get Taxonomy Module run in Orchard 1.4?

(Repost from [here](http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/discussions/348157).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the version from the gallery it will work fine with 1.4.

https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.Taxonomies

I assume you are also using a relatively old version of the source code as the 1.x branch was working on 1.4, and it has already been merged on default.